# n-bytes sized integers with different memory representation

Tags: c++, memory, integer

I'm dealing with a lot of memory represented custom integer types soon and keeping this portable, always results in the same operations. I'm think of build some sort of custom Integer class but I was wondering if such a thing already exists? For example to support something like this:

```
char * buffer_ptr = //....
UInteger<5> d( buffer_ptr, E_Type_BigEndian );
d = 20;
uint64 e = 1234567890;
d += e
```

The result would be a memory representation of a 5-Byte/40Bit unsigned Integer in BigEndian supporting assignment and maybe operations with standard host order types.

Or does boost or something offer help with that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be terribly hard to support "X bit" (or "X byte") integers for the full complement of math operations, using single byte operations, and simply either starting at the top or bottom byte to do this.

However, if you want some semblance of performance, you will not want to do that.

I worked on a project which did essentially this for integers of arbitrary bitness. However, to achieve reasonable performance for math operations (e.g. int3 x = 2; x += 5; ...), it used a 32-bit integer (64-bit int for larger than 32 bit) to perform all simple math operations, and only at the end, when the value is transferred out of the variable itself does any surplus bits get masked off. This will almost certainly improve the calculation performance by a factor of 10-100, depending on the operation and the sequences used.

As for big/little endian, again, I would use native format for the internal representation, and just convert it when it's transferred out (although I'm not sure that's a "normal" conversion - if you have "

```
 Uinteger<3> a(..., E_Type_BigEndian);
 a = 0x12345678
 uint64 b = a;
```

Surely `b` should not contain `0x78563412;`?